# angularjs using a $scope value outside of it's function in the same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function getPort() {
   $http.get($scope.newPort())
   .then(function(res) {
     $scope.scvalues = res.data;

   });
  }


$scope.dataset= [
    {
        "seriesname": $scope.scvalues.DataType,
        "Data": $scope.scvalues.Values.Data
     }];
```

HTML

```
<fusioncharts
 width="100%"
 height="600"
 type="zoomline"
 chart="{{attrs}}"
 categories="{{categories}}"
 dataset="{{dataset}}">
 </fusioncharts>
```

I'm trying to put a number string from a JSON into this fusion chart but I cannot figure out how to get scvalues out of the function.  I've tried returning it but it breaks the function and I've tried using an expression in the HTML but that breaks the chart.  I know the code under $scope.dataset is wrong but I just put it there to try to help explain my intent.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't. Set them inside the `then()` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do a thing like this

```
function getPort() {
            $http.get($scope.newPort())
            .then(function(res) {
                $scope.scvalues = res.data;
                $scope.dataset= [
                {
                    "seriesname": $scope.scvalues.DataType,
                    "Data": $scope.scvalues.Values.Data
                }];
            });
        }
```

Because you are using a [Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and it's async.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. $scope.scvalues.DataType is populating the "seriesname" field of the chart. $scope.scvalues.Values.Data is undefined and when I try do an alert on just scvalues.Values it displays [Object object].

Comment: try to show it on console using console.log($scope.scvalue.Value.Data); and open this object and check your properties.

Comment: I was able to get the second part working with a for in loop on scvalues.Values.  Thanks again for getting me pointed in the right direction.